# JS not work in bootstrap subtheme

Tags: javascript, theming, cdn

I am using bootstrap 3.6 sub-theme/cdn, I've added `scripts[] = js/custom.js` and I can see it in the source code of the page.

But... javascript is not working. 
I copied some javascript code modules to test and from my `custom.js` and still does not work.

how I can run my code javascript in my sub?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! What do you mean by _is not working_? Does it output anything?

Answer (score 0):

To put a JavaScript in your theme you must do the following steps:

Assuming that your sub-theme name is `example`.

1. Update your `example/example.info` to have this `scripts[] = js/custom.js`. That means the `custom.js` path is `example/js/custom.js`.
2. Clear the cache.

**Troubleshooting:**

If your code in `custom.js` is not working then there is something wrong. First, check if there is a js error using browser console. Second, check the `http response code` make sure that there is no permission issue.

**Alternative way to add Javascript.**

Another way of adding Javascript is by using `drupal_add_js`. With this API you can control which page the js is going to load.

Comment: But why duplicate the javascript already in the bootstrap base theme? A sub-theme should be able to re-use code from its parent/base.